# Reallign radio buttons in html form according to device orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, device-orientation

I'm fairly new to HTML and jQuery.

I'm working on an html form right now which I will use on multiple tablets. What I want is that, for example, when the tablet is portrait the available options should be shown on two rows like this:
[image: question portrait]

but when the tablet is held in landscape position, the available options should be shown on four rows like this:
[image: landscape1]

or like this if after the last radio button there is a 'text input' field (for example 'others:' '|                |')
[image: landscape2]

I was sadly rather unsuccessful in my search for an answer. I would appreciate it very much if anyone could show me how to do this (or even give an example with code).

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is definitely possible using CSS and media queries. Here's a link that should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#orientation

Comment: Please post your current code in a working fiddle (via [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/)) so we can take a look at what you have so far. Otherwise, all we can suggest is CSS media queries or using [jQuery's `resize()` method](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: @radiovisual thank you. Here is an excerpt from the questionnaire. I change the name of the questions because they were in German, and to anonymize them. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0m7mg8p4/

Comment: the fiddle and the graphic you supplied don't look the same. Is the fiddle accurate?

Comment: @radiovisual that's my problem... I'm trying to do the form the way I posted it, but I'm still new to html and jQuery. That's why I'm asking for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For starters, to create buttons that look the way they do in your layout design, you can't easily use `radio` input types.

The reason for this is that you can't style a radio button to have a text value inside of it like a button input type may have.  So in my **[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pssd46hc/6/)**, I have opted to use button input types, but you could choose to use any html tag that allows you to wrap text inside

```
<!-- Your design requires html elements that can wrap text inside -->
<input type="button" class="answer" value="CSS or JS" />
```

#### Next, to make your buttons and question responsive:

You can simply use [css media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#orientation) to achieve this. First, set your default width, then use css [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#orientation) to change any of your page's elements relative to screen size:

```
/* the default width */
.question input { width: 100px; }

/* the width when the screen is >= 700px */
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .question input { width:350px; }    
}
```

Using media-queries, you can take complete control over how the page looks at each screen size you want to target.

```
/* You can get more granular control with orientation targets: */
@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .question input { }    
}
```

**[See this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#orientation)** for more information on using media-queries.

**Media-queries are all you need to handle the responsive nature of your form.**

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

#### Bonus: Handling your form data in Javascript / jQuery

Your layout design requires that you have the ability to style your buttons in a special way (i.e. text in the middle of an element that appears like a button), but you can't style a radio button to look the way they do in your design, so you will have to "fake it", by using a common technique of turning regular html elements into interactive elements (for example: transforming a regular `<div>` or `<span>` into a button by assigning a clickable behavior to it). This is a popular technique used by developers to use CSS and Javascript to get the application's behaviors to line up with the application's design.

One obvious solution to your problem (one that wouldn't require any javascript, but would force you to change your design), is to redesign your form to only use regular `<form>` elements, in which case, you can use the `<form>` and it's submit button like normal.

So to support a custom design like yours, you have to think outside the box a little bit, and find a way to get styled html elements to "look like a button" and "act like a button"...this is very easy in javascript and CSS.

Since this topic is not totally relevant to your question (your question was geared more towards responsive design), I will briefly mention the techniques you could use to pull off your design using jQuery, and then show you a working sample.

First, since your buttons aren't real form elements anymore, you have to find a way to store, or record the user's selections (so you can process or validate them) in your application. One simple way to do this is to use jQuery, and attach a `click()` handler to each button, this will allow you to assign (or un-assign) the appearance you want to give a "selected" button, and also capture the value of the button's answer and store the value somewhere, like on a javascript object, for example). Then, when the user clicks "Submit", you can access this stored form data and do whatever your application needs to do...

### [You can see a working demo of these ideas in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/pssd46hc/6/)

Hope this helps get you started on the right path!